# Perl file parsing

Tags: python, regex, bash, perl, parsing

I have a file with the following text:

```
1152  39.955534 138.59.102.xxx -> 172.27.37.xxx HTTP 581 HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (JPEG JFIF image)

1188  42.626056 35.183.215.xxx -> 172.27.37.xxx HTTP 474 HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily

1214  42.661556 159.70.229.xxx -> 172.27.37.xxx HTTP 1496 HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (GIF89a)
...<truncated>
```

I have been trying (failing) to parse it with the Perl code below. I would like to print both IP addresses per line minus garbage. The string below:

```
perl -anle '/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/ and print $&' < my_input_file
```

The string only outputs the first column of IPs: 
138.59.102.xxx
35.183.215.xxx
159.70.229.xxx

but fails to print the 172.27.xxx.xxx addresses. Any help is appreciated, if bash or Python works I'm not opposed.

Comment: You don't need the `-a` -- it enables *autosplit* and populates the array `@F`. It's also best to give your file as a *parameter* to perl rather than push it through STDIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
perl -lne 'print $& while /[0-9x]{1,3}\.[0-9x]{1,3}\.[0-9x]{1,3}\.[0-9x]{1,3}/g' my_input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know perl but this is a python way

```
ifile = open('example.txt','r')
ofile = open('output.txt','w')
for line in ifile:
  for ip in re.findall(r'(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}',line):
    print (ip,file = ofile)
```

Comment: You're missing the dots from your regex

Comment: aaahhh whoops. i had an ugly one before with it so i tried to fix it up and i guess i must have took out too much. thanks @Borodin :)